# Can we use Kendo-React UI in React-Native?

Tags: react-native, kendo-ui, kendo-react-ui

I want to use Kendo UI React with my React Native application but I got some problems with the getting started.

I followed every step inside https://www.telerik.com/kendo-react-ui/getting-started/ but I encounter this error  :  "Invariant Violation: View config not found for name button"

So is there a way to use it in my react native mobile application ?

Comment: It's not a react-native library, usually a react-native library has a `native` implementation on the targeted OS (iOS, android or windows) as the name states, so the answer is clearly that you can't have that out of the box, as it's intended for the web use only.

Comment: is there any react native ui library?

Comment: my personal favourite is https://akveo.github.io/react-native-ui-kitten/ , but there are many out their, just search for react native ui library.

Comment: it does not include Datagrid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kendo React can´t be implemented in React native at the moment. Telerik is considering since August last year to implement it according to market demand.

https://www.telerik.com/forums/is-it-possible-to-use-kendo-ui-react-with-a-react-native-mobile-application

You should consider a different UI library or stack for your project. 
Nativescript can be a valid option depending on your needs. 
https://blog.jscrambler.com/react-native-vs-ionic-vs-nativescript-a-practical-guide/

Comment: I just need a good Datagrid in react native like we have in kendo react.